# Unreal Engine won't pack for Android because of no matching function `Stricmp` in UnrealString.h

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, unreal-engine4

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTKnH_hpU0k&list=PLW1R47Zdc1zFKMJ9FzfLQ0hjVl_rIMzW8&index=26&t=0s) to deploy my game to Android. I went through all the steps and I am using settings as suggested (SDK version 21, support arm64 enabled, support armv7 disabled):

[image]

[image]

The Launch for Windows works perfectly (also Packing for Windows - without any problems), but Packing for Android gave a lot of errors (usually very silly or regarding higher versions of C++ which I think `NVPACK` could not handle). Nerveless, I've removed all those "errors" in my code.

Unfortunately, no matter which option I choose to Pack (all, ATC, ETC, PVRTC...), I always end up with error pointing to core Unreal Engine file (precisely "UnrealString.h"):

> UATHelper: Packaging (Android (DXT)):     C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.23/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/UnrealString.h(1120,10):  error: no matching function for call to 'Stricmp'

This single error is reported 4 times. 
There are no more errors.

I am working with Unreal Engine 4.23, Visual Studio 2019, on Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 0):

In the main function is it calling stricmp or strncasecmp ? Try changing it to strncasecmp

Check [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/undefined-reference-to-%60stricmp%27-849445/) for more info on this.

Comment: You mean to modify core Unreal Engine files (UnrealString.h is not a file I've created)? I don't think it's a good idea and it would be very odd that UE4 has such a bug. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: If you have it under versioning control and can roll back the change quite easily, try changing it to see if it compiles.